# How to connect my app on Android Studio to my app on my mobile Phone through sockets?

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to create a client and server so I can connect my client app to my server through Wi-Fi. When I run my client and server both on android studio through 127.0.0.1 I can easily make a connection between them and send texts to the server from the client. However, when I install my server app on my mobile device and run the client on android studio through 192.168.43.239:8080, no connection is settled.

I must say that I make connection from my mobile device to the computer through my mobile hot-spot. I figure out the IP via the ipcommand command.

If my complete code is required, it will be provided.

Client socket programming:

```
            clientSocket=new Socket("192.168.43.239",8080);
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(tex.getText().toString());
                Message serverMessage=Message.obtain();
                ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                String strMessage=(String)ois.readObject();
                serverMessage.obj=strMessage;
```

Server socket programming:

```
              m_server=new ServerSocket(8080);
                Socket connectedSocket=m_server.accept();
                Message clientmessage=Message.obtain();
                ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(connectedSocket.getInputStream());
                String strMessage=(String)ois.readObject();
                clientmessage.obj=strMessage;
                mHandler.sendMessage(clientmessage);
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(connectedSocket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject("hi...");
                ois.close();
                oos.close();
                m_server.close();
```